# MongoDB Is copying a collection faster than updating it?

Tags: mongodb

I have several million documents in a collection. I'm required to execute a complex expression over each of them and then update a resulting value in each document.

I have tried the Eval() and javascript approach.

I have tried the Bulk Update approach.

They both take many time to complete (hours). There are no padding problems because the updated field already exists.

But, if I store the resulting documents into a new collection instead of updating the original documents, the performance is acceptable.

So, update in MongoDB is supposed to be way slower than insert?

Do you know a different approach?

Thanks!

Comment: That's because there is a lookup involved in update. What query are you using to update that doc? Is this a sharded db? If it's sharded are you using the shard key in the update?

Comment: That's what I suspect, it has to search for a document in order to update it. The interesting thing is that if you perform the update inside the javascript code when using Eval, it should internally have already a pointer to the document it is processing so the lookup is not required. But it seems not to work like that.

Comment: I think we need to see some code. I can see why inserting the documents into a new collection might be somewhat faster than updating them, but it shouldn't be make-or-break for the whole operation. What is the "accceptable" performance compared to hours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried

```
db.coll.update({}, {/* your changes here */}, { multi: true})
```

This will change all documents that match the first parameter, which is empty, so it matches all documents.

Comment: That works very well, but in my case, only one document matches the criteria:  the document Id. So, the matching criteria changes for each document and you require a new query.

Comment: I guess I don't understand the question still, my assumption was you needed to make a change to ALL documents in a collection. The empty selection criteria {} should apply your changes to all documents.

Comment: Yes, but the updating value is different for each document.